# How to extract a select set of characters between delimiters

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have text data such as this, where strings are grouped by delimiters and some words have digits attached to them:

```
reps <- c("<#> <rep> From the <{1> <[1> 1nEw 2ROyal% <,> </[1> you can see that 1fOUntain in the Dunville 2PArk% <{2> <[2> so-it-is%@ </[2> </rep>",
        "<#> <rep> <[1> That 's 2right </rep> <#> something else <rep> I 1went on my 3Own </[1> </{1> </rep>",
        "<#> <exp> <[2> Oh* 2absolUtely% </[2> </{2> </exp> <#> <rep> I know <{1> <[1> every inch </[1> and% <,> <{2> <[2> 1Every nook and 2crAnny of it% </[2> </rep>")
```

I need to extract those **digits that are inside the `<rep> ... </rep>` delimiters**. As an additional difficulty there are other digits, each preceded by either `{` or `[`, that I don't want to extract.

The desired output is this:

```
"1212" "2" "13" "12"
```

Getting rid of the unwanted digits is easy, namely with an embedded `gsub` replacement, but limiting the extraction to digits in-between the `<rep> ... </rep>` delimiters is much harder. My hunch is that lookbehind and lookahead will be part of the solution. Just how to implement them is unclear to me. This is what I've tried but it's quite imperfect:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(gsub("(?<=\\{|\\[)\\d", "", reps, perl = T), "(?<=<rep>)(?!</rep>).*\\d.*?(?=</rep>)")
[[1]]
[1] " From the <{> <[> 1nEw 2ROyal% <,> </[> you can see that 1fOUntain in the Dunville 2PArk% <{> <[> so-it-is%@ </[> "

[[2]]
[1] " <[> That 's 2right </rep> <#> something else <rep> I 1went on my 3Own </[> </{> "

[[3]]
[1] " I know <{> <[> every inch </[> and% <,> <{> <[> 1Every nook and 2crAnny of it% </[> "
```

Any insight?

**EDIT**:

A `stringr`solution arrived at with insight from @GK's answer:

```
gsub("\\D", "", unlist(lapply(gsub("(?<=\\{|\\[)\\d", "", reps, perl = T), function(x) str_extract_all(x, "<rep>.*?</rep>"))))
[1] "1212" "2"    "13"   "12"
```

Comment: Isn't the third result `13` instead of `3`?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, thanks for spotting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first replace the numbers you are not interested in starting with `[` or `{` using `gsub`. Then extract the part between `<rep>` and `</rep>` using `gregexpr` and `regmatches` and then remove everything what is not a number using `gsub` again.

```
x <- gsub("(\\{|\\[)\\d+", "", reps)
unlist(lapply(regmatches(x, gregexpr("<rep>.*?</rep>", x)),
  gsub, pattern="\\D", replacement=""))
#[1] "1212" "2"    "13"   "12"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just one question: how would the solution have to be changed to get two the results from the 2nd string pasted together, like so: `"1212" "2, 13"   "12"`?

Comment: Try: `sapply(lapply(regmatches(x, gregexpr("<rep>.*?</rep>", x)), gsub, pattern="\\D", replacement=""), paste, collapse = ", ")`